# Dynamic Named Ranges and VBA error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a dynamic named range for 'r_clusterSchedule' using the following formulae in the Name Manager:

```
=OFFSET(Scheduling!$B$15,0,0,COUNTA(Scheduling!$B$15:$B$214),1)
```

I then refer to this dynamic named range in VBA as

```
AClusterSchedule = Range("r_clusterSchedule")
```

I then get a Run-time error 1004. Method 'Range of Object'_Global' failed.

Any ideas on using dynamic named ranges (Name Manager with Offset formula) with Excel VBA?

Comment: Hm, the object may need to be Set `Set AClusterSchedule = Range("r_clusterSchedule")`...maybe.

Comment: Hey Bmo, I'm actually just using AClusterSchedule = Range("r_clusterSchedule")

Comment: Not that familiar with `OFFSET` sorry. I have a test going, when I use offset to specify 5 cells, when I reference in VBA it's only pointing to the one. Maybe evaluate the offset in VBA, or use indirect.

Comment: @Shiraj Bmo is corrects. You need to declare `Dim AClusterSchedule As Range` and then use Set to assign the it. Now make sure your `Named Ranged` formula doesn't return an error. If it does, it will error out in code (VBA).

Comment: @L42 I've declared it as Variant. Let me try Range

Comment: At least one cell in `Scheduling!$B$15:$B$214` must contain something. Otherwise `COUNTA(Scheduling!$B$15:$B$214)` count 0 and produces a Height 0 in `Offset` which results in `#REF`error.